# How to do the following replace in vim?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to replace all of the occurrences of

```
armv7_format_strings<any_string> = {<str1>, <str2>};
```

by

```
armv7_format_strings<any_string>[0] = <str1> ;
armv7_format_strings<any_string>[1] = <str2> ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one worked:

```
%s/\(armv7_format_strings.*\) = {\(.*\), \(.*\)};/\1[0] = \2;\r\1[1] = \3;\r/gc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a substation with a sub-replace-expression.

```
:%s/^\(\s*armv7_format_strings.*\) = {\([^}]*\)};/\=join(map(split(submatch(2), '\s*,\s*'), 'submatch(1)."[".v:key."] = ".v:val.";"'),"\r")/
```

#### Overview

Basically this captures the left hand side (`{lhs}`) and the right hand side (`{rhs}`) separately. Then splits the `{rhs}` by `,` (aka parameter) and concatenates the `{lhs}` to each new parameter. Finish the substitution by joining each new line together with a new line, `"\r"`.

Note: this will fail for tricky strings, e.g. `"foo,bar"` as this method just assumes no `,` or `}` inside of strings.

#### Glory of Details

- `%s:^\(\s*armv7_format_strings.*\) = {\([^}]*\)};/\={expr}/` - Capture the `{lhs}` and `{rhs}`
- use an sub-replace-expression, `\={expr}`, to use `{expr}` as the replacement.
- `submatch(1)` is the `{lhs}` aka `\1` in normal regex speak
- `submatch(2)` is the `{rhs}` aka `\2` in normal regex speak
- `split(submatch(2), '\s*,\s*')` - split the `{rhs}` by `,`. Yields are parameters as a List
- `map({lst}, {expr})` - `map()` will update the list by evaluating `{expr}`
- use `submatch(1)."[".v:key."] = ".v:val.";"` as our expression, `{expr}`
- `v:val` will the each single item in the List
- `v:key` will the the index of the List
- `join({lst}, "\r")` will join the list together as new lines

#### For more help

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h join(
:h map(
:h split(
:h submatch(
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'd use the regex swap you could also do it with a macro.

```
qq^vt=h"ayf{lvt,"byf,lvt}"cydd<CTRL_r>a[0] = <CTRL_r>b;<Enter><CTRL_r>a[1] = <CTRL_r>c;q
```

Its basically the same as the regex. Yank the left side of the equals into register a, and the two strings in the array into registers b and c. Delete the line, and paste `RegA[0] = RegB;\nRegA[1] = RegC;`